# How can I use the selected data from a UIDatePicker in another view in IOS8?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, popover, uidatepicker

I'm very new to IOS 8 and programming in general.  I would like to populate a UIButton's label text with the value from a UIDatePicker.  When the user presses the button, a popover appears with a date picker.  I have created a new view controller imbedded in a navigation controller for my date picker.  They are connected using a popover segue.  My question is once the user selects a date, how can I transmit this information back to the original view controller to show the value on the button label.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: thanks very much for the useful link.  i decided on an unwind segue to get back to my original view which works just fine.  but i still don't know how to get the data that was selected in the picker back to the original view.  much of the link was in objective-c which i am not familiar with.  i just wanted the basic concept and will do the work myself to learn how to implement it.  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass a value between 2 viewcontrollers using segues is easies done like this:

```
class VC1:UIViewController {
    @IBAction func next() {
        let valueToPass = NSDate() // Could be anything that conforms to AnyObject
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueID", sender: valueToPass) // Use this method unless you're connecting a button to a viewcontroller in storyboard
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let vc2 = segue.destinationViewController as VC2 // The viewcontroller you're going to
        vc2.date = sender as NSDate // If you connected button to vc in storyboard sender will be nil, so in that case just set the vc2.date directly here
    }
}


class VC2:UIViewController {
    var date:NSDate! // Property you want to pass to
}
```